# Jquery handle logourt on window close method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a popup window and I am trying to fire an event on close in order to `logout()` the user.

My code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        return confirm("");
    }); 
});
```

When I close the close button I am getting like that:

[image]

From where the **false** coming from? And **I want to put my on message** instead of `Are you want to leave this page?`

If I click the Leave this page button the there should be a provision to call `logout()` or just stay on page otherwise.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

`beforeunload` event handler MUST return a string, which will be displayed as the prompt message. The `false` you saw in the dialog is the stringified return value of `confirm()` function. And the message "Are you want to leave this page?" is defined by the browser and is NOT script-controllable.

Basically you cannot bind a function onto `beforeunload` event. This is due to the page security, otherwise binding an `alert()` will prevent the user from closing the window permanently.

Furthermore, I don't think your original requirement "logout when user close the window" is feasible. Partially because of the technical issue addressed above. Actually, even if you were able to implement that in a "magical" way, there are too many ways for the user to close the browser without calling your `logout()`, e.g. killing the browser process, cut the computer power...therefore, your app SHOULD NOT rely on the front-end to logout -- it should keep the session alive for only limited time -- say, 20 mins -- and invalidate the session after it is expired.

Comment: can You suggest a fiddle or an sample will more helpful.

Comment: As updated, please use server-side session timeout mechanism to logout user. You shouldn't rely on browser closing behavior.